# Rails Nested Attributes 3 level depth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I have the models `series` `seasons` and `episodes`. From within `series/new` form I want to create a series, season and episode all together. I'm reading [Rails Routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) and [Nested Forms](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#nested-forms) guides but I don't know what I'm doing wrong as the guide doesn't cover a 3 level depth. When using the nested form, Rails is only inserting the `Series` and `Season` values **but not the `Episode` values**.

Is my approach even correct? I'd appreciate any input~

```
# series.rb
has_many :seasons, dependent: :destroy
has_many :episodes, :through => :seasons
accepts_nested_attributes_for :seasons
accepts_nested_attributes_for :episodes

# season.rb
belongs_to :series
has_many :episodes, dependent: :destroy

# episode.rb
belongs_to :season

# routes.rb
resources :series, except: [:show, :new] do
  resources:seasons, except: [:show], path: '' do
    resources :episodes, path: ''
  end
end
```

## series/new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @series do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
    <%= f.fields_for :seasons do |seasons_form| %>
      <%= seasons_form.text_field :title %>
      <%= seasons_form.fields_for :episodes do |episodes_form| %>
        <%= episodes_form.text_field :title %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: Are you receiving episod's attributes in params hash? If yes, then have you whitelisted episode's attributes?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this is my series_params: `def series_params
    params.require(:person).permit(:title, seasons_attributes: [:id, :title], episodes_attributes: [:id, :title])
  end`

Comment: @Dotol were you able to solve this problem?

Comment: I wasn't able to, gave up a while ago. I'd appreciate some insight into what I was doing wrong or a possible solution/workaround

Comment: I know this is 5 years old but I currently have the same problem. Any solutions?

Answer (score 3):

## series.rb

```
has_many :seasons, dependent: :destroy
has_many :episodes, :through => :seasons

accepts_nested_attributes_for :seasons
accepts_nested_attributes_for :episodes
```

## season.rb

```
belongs_to :series
has_many :episodes, dependent: :destroy

accepts_nested_attributes_for :episodes
```

## episode.rb

```
belongs_to :season
```

As you have used `has_many :episodes, :through => :seasons` , episodes parameters will be inside the `hash` of `seasons`. So you need to make a slight change in `series_params` method:

## series controller

```
def new
  @series = Series.new
  #build objects of nested
  @season = @series.seasons.build  
  @episod = @season.episods.build
end

def series_params 
  params.require(:series).permit(:title, 
   seasons_attributes: [:id, :title, episodes_attributes: [:id, :title]]) 
end
```

Note: It is static. For dynamic object building, here is a good [screencast](https://www.driftingruby.com/episodes/nested-forms-from-scratch)

Comment: I did precisely that and it still doesn't save episodes these are my params and form letter by letter: def series_params                                                                                 
      `params.require(:series).permit(:title, seasons_attributes: [:id, :title, episodes_attributes: [:id, :title]])
    end`

Comment: And my form: `<%= form_for @series do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>

    <%= f.fields_for :seasons do |ff| %>
      <%= ff.text_field :title %>
      <%= ff.fields_for :episodes do |fff| %>
        <%= fff.text_field :title %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.submit %>
  <% end %>`

Comment: can you post your input params hash? You can find it on server log when you submit the form.

Comment: web_1   | Processing by SeriesController#create as HTML
web_1   |   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"M0TA7cDoiS4mQBudQWfQ+DVBQZw2r29kq8baRucakpvbzSsYyLHSWRnVEJ2UnhqVkVpvrugzphvRHMpyN+JMCw==", "series"=>{"title"=>"jabrone", "seasons_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"title"=>"jabroni 2", "episodes"=>{"title"=>"jabronium 3"}}}}, "commit"=>"Create Series"}

Comment: In your season model, accept its nested params, that is episode's attributes. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense but by adding accepts_nested_attrs~ to my season model removes my episodes text_field for some reason. Should I also edit my form in some way?

Comment: It is because, you may not have build episod's object in your controller's new method.

Comment: Interesting, I have series_controller.rb def new @series.episodes.build end but I have this in my routes.rb -> resources :series, except: [:show, :new]   resources :series, only: [:new], path: 'shows'  So to access my series/new the URL would be shows/new not series/new, could that be the culprit? And thanks again Hasmukh~

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153719/discussion-between-dotol-and-hasmukh-rathod).

Comment: For time being, can you remove nested routes and make them individual like resources :series, resources :seasons, resources :episods

Comment: If I have normal routes (not nested) my series/new doesn't show episodes text_field if I have accepts_nested_attributes_for :episodes in seasons.rb model, and if i remove accepts_nested_atts~ from seasons the episodes text field appears, but if i submit the form it still doesnt save episodes value

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
# series.rb
has_many :seasons, dependent: :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :seasons
accepts_nested_attributes_for :episodes
```

with

```
# series.rb
has_many :seasons, dependent: :destroy
has_many :episodes, :through => :seasons
accepts_nested_attributes_for :seasons
accepts_nested_attributes_for :episodes
```

Comment: This makes sense actually can't believe I thought of that, checking in a bit once I have access to a computer.

Comment: This [code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/d0d7ce001bdbb0e5551da881caf8156c06238b84/activerecord/lib/active_record/nested_attributes.rb) shows how rails defined `accepts_nested_attributes_for`.

if `if reflection = _reflect_on_association(association_name)` is nil,  
`raise ArgumentError, "No association found for name \`#{association_name}'. Has it been defined yet?"`

 occurred.

Comment: Thanks @Aoi_777 I updated the original post to further detail how episodes isn't being saved

Answer (score 0):

You need to move `accepts_nested_attributes_for :episodes` from the series model to the season model since the seasons form, `<%= seasons_form.fields_for :episodes ... %>` is accepting attributes for the `episodes`

Comment: That would throw an undefined method 'episodes' in my build statement.